# Different behavior in browser and nodejs on calling typeof in new Function

Tags: javascript, node.js

The following code is behaving differently in broswers and nodejs:

```
var a = function() {}; 
var isFunction = function(funcName){    
  var f =
  new Function ("return typeof " + funcName + "=== 'function'");    
  return    f(); 
};
console.log(isFunction("a"));
```

In Browsers, it logs as true. However, saving as a js file and running in nodejs, it logs false. Can anyone let me know why?

Comment: Node returned `true` for me. v0.10.34

Comment: Same here in node v0.10.28. Both `true`.

Comment: And 10.31; what version are you using? Is the code exactly as you're using?

Comment: I am using v0.12.1. It ouputs false....

Comment: Code are identical..

Comment: Node returns true for me on v0.12.1, OSX.

Comment: It is really weird. If I run it line by line in node console, it will give true. But if I save it to file and run it by node, it will give false...

Comment: Really interesting - `"a"` is inlined as a quoted String in a node script, but a reference to `a` when running in the Node/Chrome 42 REPL.